# How to parse JSON string in ASP.NET MVC view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, json-deserialization

I am inserting JSON string into table, than on listing page in View inside foreach loop I want to parse that JSON string using Razor

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    var pr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(item.profile);
    //getting error 
    //the 'JsonConvert' does not exist in corrent context
    //and also the return type Profile was showing error so I changed it to `dynamic`
     <tr>
         <td>@pr.Name</td>
}
```

Comment: Why don't you deserialize your object of type Profile in your controller and the send it to your razor view as a List?

Comment: because then I have to use 2 loops, one process it in controller than at view to show

Comment: You do not need to loop to deserialize your object in your controller. Just use`var pr=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Profile>(item.profile.ToString());` in your controller and then loop over pr which I assume is a List to get your properties on your razor view.

Comment: Or if you really want to parse your JSON string in your View, try: `var pr = JSON.parse(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(item.profile))); // returns Object`

Comment: `'JSON' does not exist in current context` I am writing this in VIEW

Comment: JSON.parse is a JavaScript function and not a c# function. You would have to parse your string in <script> section of your razor view and then bind them to your table structure.

Comment: but i need to parse it using C# Razor

Comment: Then add the following line in your view: `@using Newtonsoft.Json;` .This will get your JsonConvert method to run in your view.

Answer (score 0):

When your application grows large you will feel it's better to use the standard approach of Model-View-Controller. It may become difficult to recode your application at that time. You can use this approach instead:

1. Create a class for JSON response.
2. Create a Model class that includes JSON class as a property, and all the other things required by your View.
3. Fetch the JSON from Controller, feed it to the Model, and return the Model to the View.
4. Traverse the Model (not JSON) in your View.

If you're just testing something temporarily then you can add `@using Newtonsoft.Json` on top of your view to make it recognize the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method.

Comment: Yes, this is pretty much what I was trying to explain to the OP. Using the traditional MVC approach is the best and most efficient way.